# Find rows where related row is the same

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to find rows in part id, i.e column name `PID` where the supplier id i.e `S_ID` is same for that part id.

```
+----+-----+
|PID | SID |
+----+-----+
| 11 |  31 |
| 12 |  35 |
| 11 |  32 |
| 11 |  35 |
| 13 |  34 |
+----+-----+
```

I am expecting the result as following:

```
+----+-----+
|PID | SID |
+----+-----+
| 11 |  31 |
| 11 |  32 |
| 11 |  35 |
+----+-----+
```

I tried running the query as following but getting an empty table.

```
SELECT S_ID FROM P_CATALOG
GROUP BY PID, S_ID
HAVING COUNT(S_ID)>1
```

What should I do?

Comment: `select PID, S_ID from P_Catalog where PID = 11`

Comment: If the above query is not what you have in mind, then please elaborate on what the logic is which arrives at your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two steps to build a query.

1) Find all `PID`s that have more than one row:

```
SELECT PID
FROM P_CATALOG
GROUP BY PID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

2) Return original rows from the table with the found `PID`s:

```
SELECT PID, SID
FROM P_CATALOG
WHERE
    PID IN 
    (
        SELECT PID
        FROM P_CATALOG
        GROUP BY PID
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    )
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your sample results, you seem to want `PID`s that have multiple `SID`s.  `EXISTS` is a simple way to do this:

```
select c.*
from p_catalog c
where exists (select 1 
              from p_catalog c2
               where c2.pid = c.pid and c2.sid <> c.sid
             );
```

This is not exactly what you are asking, but it is the most sensible interpretation of the data you have provided.